# required angular IOS yearly calendar as in[https://github.com/MariemChaabeni/angular-calendar-year-view] for angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

required angular IOS yearly calendar as in [https://github.com/MariemChaabeni/angular-calendar-year-view] which is build on angular7.
But while using it in angular6, show me ts1005 ; expected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using old version of TypeScript. To check your version run command `tsc --version`.

If your version is older than the latest(3.3.3333), locate it with `which tsc` command, and remove it.

Uninstall the global TypeScript with the command `npm uninstall -g typescript`, and install the latest stable version with command: `npm install -g typescript`